# Changing CSS properties using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I am trying to change the UL image in the CSS folder using jQuery. This is for a Twitter stream, where the avatar of the account posting is changed alongside the tweet. 
Using `.css` is pretty straight forward, but I am struggling to change the URL for the new image.

Here is my client code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io();

    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('info', function(data){
        console.log("this is teh question" + " " + data);
        $("#tweets").prepend("<li>" + data + "</li>");
    });

    socket.on('reply', function(data){
        console.log("this is my reply" + " " + data);
        $("#messages").prepend("<li>" + data + "</li>");
    });

    socket.on('userPic', function(data) {
        console.log("the userPic: " + data);
        $("ul#tweets").css("list-style-image: url", data);
    });
});
```

And the CSS:

```css
body {
    font: 13px Helvetica, Arial;
    max-width: 1250px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

form {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

form input {
    border: 3px inset;
    padding: 7px 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 140px);
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
}

form button {
    width: 110px;
    background: #177cc1;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form button:hover {
    background: #177cee;
}

form button:active {
    background: #177caa;
}

form button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px 10px 20px;
    background: #222;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #555;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

.tweets_container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

.header {
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    padding: 15px;
}

#messages, #tweets {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(50% - 32px);
}

#tweets li, #messages li {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#messages {
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#tweets {
    list-style-image: url("");
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

ul#messages {
    list-style-image: url("");
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#tweets {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.footer {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this:

```
$("ul#tweets").css("list-style-image: url", data);
```

should be changed to:

```
$("ul#tweets").css("list-style-image", "url('"+data+"')");
```

Comment: correct answer although I don't see where anyone suggested the first example for it to be changed to the correct one you put below it.

Comment: it was edited, wasn't there before when I saw the OP

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly :). Why do you need the +data+?

Comment: inside of the `data` variable there is the url for the image. now in order to concatenate it I need to break out of the string using `"` then use the `+` to concatenate it and then continue the string using another `+`

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your nodejs and socket.io, check if `socket.on('userPic', function(data) {`, the userPic event is being fired. If so, check if the valid of `data` is valid for this scenario.

The way `list-style-image` works is that it requires a working url in a format of `list-style-image:url('')`, so your data argument needs to be a valid image path wrapped by parentheses as well as quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Because css just deals with simple property value pairs, your JS will need to update the entire of the value in order to work. Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/xhnr7e91/6/), click on the image to see the change (I used background image for simplicity, there's no difference beyond the name of the property and the principle of providing a fully formed property value is demonstrated) ...

```
$('.image').css(
    'background-image', 
    'url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/")'
);
```

You would use something like this to take a variable:

```
$('.image').css(
    'background-image', 
    'url("' + data + '")'
);
```

This is the same as any other css property change. The whole value on the right needs to be updated in order for it to work. A similar problem people sometimes encounter is forgetting to add a unit to size value such as width and putting a number straight in:

```
.css('width', number); // wrong
.css('width', number + '%'); // right
```

Comment: the question was asking about dynamically updating list-style-image,  which is a legitimate approach, not updating the background image.

Comment: @max7 I was using background-image as a simple of example of the problem he was seeing, it makes no difference what the property on the left is, also, I'm not here just to dump correct code for a copy and paste, I'd rather explain with an example so the OP can change their own code themselves and actually learn something

Comment: the property to the left absolutely does make a difference and I'm not sure which is more shocking, the fact that I have to say it or the fact that you made a such an obviously factually challenged statement in the first place.

Don't dump code but do speak to the actual question asked, it's that simple.

Comment: @max7 - what is the difference? as far as i can see it's identical apart from the name: they both use a URL property which needs to be spliced rather than directly dropped in if you just have an actual URL

Comment: Thanks, your example helped me understand the concept behind the problem

Comment: @ToniLeigh - the difference is that list-style-image confers a background on the child elements of the parent ul whereas background image sets it directly the element it is placed.  Yes they are close but there is a difference and you would write different styles for each. point is, I would never say to a bginer that property doesn't matter. Also, OP was indeed attempting to update the entire value of the css, but his jquery syntax was incorrect and he did not concat his variable, as Saar pointed out. That said, your post is interesting but incongruent with the OP, imo.

Comment: @max7 I think the precise details of how the property renders are irrelevant

Comment: @ToniLeigh  you do realize that in one sentence, you've just negated the very purpose why anyone would write CSS?

Comment: @max7 i mean irrelevant to the solution to the OPs problem